# How to prevent automatic updates being applied to the Cloud SQL instance

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How to prevent automatic updates being applied to the Cloud SQL instance. I see Type as Update and Status as Done for many entries. Its a MySQL 5.7 instance. How should I prevent Updates on my Cloud SQL instance?

https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#maintenancerestart

Comment: How often do you see them? They are not necessarily system updates. Most edits (incl for example editing network ACLs) will show up as updates. You can check the 'acitivity' log in Cloud Logging to see if they are user initiated. System initiated entries will not show up in the activity log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud SQL is a fully-managed database service, so it's not possible to prevent automatic updates. As you can see in the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#version), minor updates are deployed as they are released. If you have a second-generation instance, you might want to consider a preferred [maintenance window](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#maintenance-window-2ndgen) that will be less disruptive for your application.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is probably not possible. Cloud SQL is a hosted service, and comes with built-in infrastructure support. AFAIK the only way to have absolute control over your DB software is to run it on a GCE instance, rather than on a Cloud SQL instance.